# Digest authentication in Python?

Tags: python, authentication, ntlm, digest

I'm trying to access pages from my company server with python. The first trail return 401: Unathorized(the server does need domain username/pwd for authentication). And the header content is as follow, and it seems to support 3 authentication protocols, Negotiate, NTLM and Digest, so in my understanding, I can choose any of them, right?

```
Content-Type: text/html
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.0
WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate
WWW-Authenticate: NTLM
WWW-Authenticate: Digest qop="auth",algorithm=MD5-sess,nonce="+Upgraded+v184080dc2d18fe10d63520db505929b5b5b929ec98692ce010e80d6347b7a35d4027e59e277ac4fe1c257a95196071258a8e0797bf6129f76",charset=utf-8,realm="Digest"
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Tue, 06 Aug 2013 09:24:44 GMT
Connection: close
Content-Length: 1293
Set-Cookie: LB-INFO=1065493258.20480.0000; path=/
```

I'm using following python codes, but still got 401 unanthorized error, can anybody tell me how can i achieve it? Should I use NTLM? Thanks in advance!

```
p = urllib2.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()
p.add_password(None, self.url, username, password)
handler = urllib2.HTTPDigestAuthHandler(p)
opener = urllib2.build_opener(handler)
urllib2.install_opener(opener)

f = opener.open(self.url)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`urllib2` is the python standard library, but not necessarily the best tool for HTTP Requests.

I would highly recommend checking out the `requests` package, and you can find an authentication tutorial here: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/authentication/#digest-authentication

Comment: Thanks, I made it using requests!

`requests.get(url,auth=HttpNtlmAuth('domain\\username',pwd))`

Answer (score 15):

Another very popular form of HTTP Authentication is [Digest Authentication](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/authentication/#digest-authentication), and  Requests supports this out of the box as well:

```
from requests.auth import HTTPDigestAuth
url = 'http://httpbin.org/digest-auth/auth/user/pass'
requests.get(url, auth=HTTPDigestAuth('user', 'pass'))
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer

Comment: Thanks for this tip.  This is exactly what I needed to send requests to my crappy Amcrest wireless security camera.  I was struggling for a couple of hours until I found this.  The API said something about 'Digest Authentication' which led me to search for that.